# Saving space by hard-linking duplicates

Tags: bash

I am looking for tool, script etc to hard link (or something equivalent) files with the purpose of saving space.

(Going through files, finding duplicates and hard-linking them in).

Will also then pure analysis - to find "duplicates", and see which ones are actually the same physical files.

Comment: Safe, yes, as the actual file will not be deleted until all hard-links are deleted. iPhoto/Photos Library is one example of where this is already done. As to automated, sorry, I've no idea.

Comment: Time Machine works EXACTLY like this. OS X is even able to hardlink directories.

Comment: I've removed the opinion-based part of your question. Also it might help to know a bit more about your specific needs (and the files you are looking at). Optimizing space usage in a standard OS X installation is probably not worth the trouble, are you looking at some specific user-generated files?

Comment: we have duplicates between iPhoto and the new thing (Photos?).

Comment: As mentioned in my earlier comment, iPhoto & Photos are already hard-linked. They don't take up as much room as the Finder would suggest. Finder file sizes do not check for hard links.

Comment: Between instances?  (We upgraded but still use iPhoto, also the iPhoto was from another machine)

Comment: Could this script work?:
http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/ANDK/Perl-Repository-APC-2.002/eg/trimtrees.pl
(On Windows there are GUI programs)

Comment: When you migrate your photo library from iPhoto/Aperture to Photos, the image files automatically get hard-linked into the new library (so they don't take up more space than before). This of course does not apply to images you add to both libraries *after* the migration.